# ParseError while parsing AndroidManifest.xml in python

Tags: python, xml, android-manifest

I'm trying to parse an AndroiManifest.xml file to get informations and I have this error when I'm charging my file

> xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token):
>   line 1, column 0

Here is my code :

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

tree = ET.ElementTree(file='AndroidManifest.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

My XML file seems well formed :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:versionCode="132074037"
    android:versionName="193.0.0.21.98"
    android:installLocation="0"
    package="com.facebook.orca">
```

How can I fix that and parse my XML to get a 'android:versionName' tag ?

Comment: is that your entire `manifest.xml` file? if not then you need to close out the manifest element by changing to `package="com.facebook.orca"/>`. but as your error is complaining about line 1 column 0, I'm not sure what the issue is as I don't receive that error. ensure that there is no whitespace in line 1 column 0

Comment: @smoggers No the file is more than 5k lines long and finishes by </manifest>
. And there is no whitespace in line 1 column 0

Answer (score 1):

Solved

I was trying to parse an AndroidManifest.xml after I've unzipped an apk but with this method, the AndroidManifest.xml is encoded so it's impossible to open, read or parse it. I was able to read it only by using Android Studio that automatically decodes an AndroidManifest file.

To parse an AndroidManifest.xml after unzipping an apk, the best way is to use aapt command line :

```
 /Users/{Path_to_your_sdk}/sdk/build-tools/28.0.3/aapt dump
 badging com.squareup.cash.apk | sed -n
 "s/.*versionName='\([^']*\).*/\1/p"
```

And you will obtain the versionName of your app. Hope it will help.